React Component not found during unit test (using jest and react testing library)
I'm working with an Autocomplete component in React where I need to conditionally render a "Load More" button based on the option.is_for_load_more property. However, the component is not found during test even I have mocked the component and set option.is_for_load_more explicitly to true
Here’s the component code:
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Autocomplete, AutocompleteItem } from '@nextui-org/autocomplete';
import { IAsyncAutocompleteProps } from '@/types/components/master-data';
import {
  ICity,
  TBank,
  TVoucherType,
  ICountry,
  IState,
  IDistrict,
  TAllFormTypeWithoutMembership,
  IDoctor,
  IOrganization
} from '@/types/master-data.type';
import { getNoOptionsText, renderFirstValue, renderValue } from '@/common/master-data-form';
import { useGetMasterDataList } from '@/services/master-data/master-data.service';
import { toast } from 'sonner';
import { cityDummy } from '@/__tests__/mock/master-data/tab-subtab-data.mock';
import { Button } from '@/components/button/base-button.component';

const AsyncAutocomplete = ({
  formField,
  isDisabled,
  field,
  onChangeValue,
  inputValues,
  unitChangeValue,
  handleInputChange
}: IAsyncAutocompleteProps) => {
  const [isFetchOptionsLoading, setIsFetchOptionsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [autocompleteOptions, setAutocompleteOptions] = useState<
    TBank[] | IState[] | ICountry[] | ICity[] | TVoucherType[] | IDistrict[] | IDoctor[] | IOrganization[]
  >([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState({
    page_no: 1,
    per_page: 5,
    ecrf: ['id'],
    is_active: true
  });
  const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(1);
  const timeoutRef = useRef<ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | null>(null);

  const getListItemsForOptions = useGetMasterDataList({
    onMutate: () => {
      setIsFetchOptionsLoading(true);
    },
    onSuccess: (response) => {
      const temp = autocompleteOptions;
      if (autocompleteOptions.length > 0) {
        temp.pop();
      }

      setAutocompleteOptions([
        ...temp,
        ...(response.data as
          | TBank[]
          | IState[]
          | ICountry[]
          | ICity[]
          | TVoucherType[]
          | IDistrict[]
          | IDoctor[]
          | IOrganization[]),
        { code: '', name: '', is_for_load_more: true }
      ]);
      setIsFetchOptionsLoading(false);
      setQuery({ ...query, page_no: query.page_no + 1 });
      setLastPage(response.pagination.total_page);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        toast.error(error.message, { closeButton: true });
      }

      setAutocompleteOptions(cityDummy);
      setIsFetchOptionsLoading(false);
    }
  });

  const fetchAutocompleteOptions = (formFieldValue: string, value: string) => {
    getListItemsForOptions.mutate({
      type: formFieldValue,
      query: {
        ...query,
        name: value
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setAutocompleteOptions([]);
    if (field.value?.name) {
      fetchAutocompleteOptions(formField.value, String(field.value?.name));
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const handleKeyDown = (value: string) => {
    if (timeoutRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);
    }

    if (value?.length < 3) {
      setIsFetchOptionsLoading(false);

      return;
    }

    timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      fetchAutocompleteOptions(formField.value, value);
    }, 500);
  };

  const isFocusedRef = useRef(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        {...field}
        onFocus={() => {
          isFocusedRef.current = true;
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
          isFocusedRef.current = false;
        }}
        selectedKey={field.value ? Number(field.value?.id) : undefined}
        inputValue={inputValues[formField.value]}
        aria-label={formField.label}
        data-testid={`${formField.value}-async-autocomplete`}
        items={autocompleteOptions as object[]}
        disabled={isDisabled}
        placeholder={formField.placeholder}
        allowsEmptyCollection={true}
        isInvalid={Boolean(inputValues[formField.value] && inputValues[formField.value]?.length < 3)}
        onSelectionChange={(key) => {
          if (!isFocusedRef.current) return;
          if (!key) return;

          let selectedValue = renderValue(formField.value, key as number, autocompleteOptions) as
            | TBank
            | IState
            | ICountry
            | ICity
            | TVoucherType
            | IDistrict
            | IDoctor;

          if (!selectedValue) {
            selectedValue = renderFirstValue(formField.value, autocompleteOptions) as
              | TBank
              | IState
              | ICountry
              | ICity
              | TVoucherType
              | IDistrict
              | IDoctor;
          }

          if (onChangeValue) {
            onChangeValue(formField.value, selectedValue);
            field.onChange(selectedValue);
          }
          if (unitChangeValue) {
            const value = {
              ...selectedValue
            } as IOrganization;
            unitChangeValue(value);
          }
          handleInputChange(formField.value, selectedValue?.name ?? '');
        }}
        listboxProps={{
          emptyContent: getNoOptionsText(inputValues[formField.value], isFetchOptionsLoading),
          hideEmptyContent: inputValues[formField.value] != '' && inputValues[formField.value]?.length < 3
        }}
        allowsCustomValue={Boolean(inputValues[formField.value])}
        onInputChange={(value) => {
          setIsFetchOptionsLoading(true);
          handleInputChange(formField.value, value);
          handleKeyDown(value);
        }}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }}
        menuTrigger="focus"
        shouldCloseOnBlur={true}
        value={field.value || null}
        isClearable={false}
        isLoading={isFetchOptionsLoading}
        variant={formField.variant}
        labelPlacement={formField.labelPlacement}
      >
        {(option: TAllFormTypeWithoutMembership) => (
          <AutocompleteItem
            aria-label={`${option[formField.optionLabel as keyof typeof option]}`}
            key={`${option.id}`}
            data-testid={`${option.id}-option`}
          >
            {option.is_for_load_more ? (
              <>
                {Number(query.page_no) < Number(lastPage) ? (
                  <div className="flex justify-center">
                    <Button
                      className="mt-5 bg-white text-[#1B5E20] py-1 px-2 rounded-md border border-[#1B5E20]"
                      aria-label="load more"
                      onClick={() => fetchAutocompleteOptions(formField.value, inputValues[formField.value])}
                    >
                      Load More
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                ) : null}
              </>
            ) : (
              option[formField.optionLabel as keyof typeof option]
            )}
          </AutocompleteItem>
        )}
      </Autocomplete>
      {inputValues[formField.value] && inputValues[formField.value]?.length < 3 && (
        <span className="text-xs text-red-600">To search for data, type at least 3 characters</span>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default AsyncAutocomplete;

Here is the the test code using jest and react testing library:
it('renders Load More button', async () => {
    const mockMutate = jest.fn((params) => {
      if (params && typeof params.onSuccess === 'function') {
        params.onSuccess({
          data: [...cityDummy, { id: 'load-more', name: '', is_for_load_more: true }],
          pagination: { total_page: 10 }
        });
      }
    });
    mockUseGetMasterDataList.mockImplementation(() => ({ mutate: mockMutate }));

    const { getByPlaceholderText, getByText } = render(
      <AsyncAutocomplete 
        formField={formField} 
        isDisabled={false} 
        field={field} 
        onChangeValue={onChangeValue} 
        inputValues={{ city: '' }} 
        handleInputChange={handleInputChange} 
      />
    );

    fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText('Input city'), { target: { value: 'test' } });
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockMutate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });

    const loadMoreButton = getByText('Load More');
    expect(loadMoreButton).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

Why is it not found during test? and how to fix this so it can be found on test?
Please help..

it seems like Number(query.page_no) < Number(lastPage)
will never met because you are mocking useGetMasterDataList
